# Freeze Ubuntu 18.04 on HP OMEN

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, freeze

I love Ubuntu but I can't use it on my Notebook Hp Omen 15-ce001la I5-7300hq Gtx1050.

I installed many times the 18.04 and 18.04.01 and the problem continues.... **after the log in and welcome window, it freeze and i can use it.**

I think that is the nvidia video card (Gtx1050), but i cant disable by the bios.

I need to solve this or I will need to sell my notebook to buy another. 
please help!
Best!